# Is it possible to estimate transaction fee without using a private key?

Tags: node, key, fee, conseiljs

As far as I know, in order to estimate a fee of a Tezos transaction, a following method needs to be called on a Tezos node: `../<block_id>/helpers/scripts/run_operation` . At least this is how it's implemented in [ConseilJS](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/blob/master/src/chain/tezos/TezosNodeWriter.ts#L606) and that's what I found in [documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html).

One of the parameters of that method is a transaction signature that obviously requires using a private key.

My question is: is it possible to estimate fee **without** using a private key? I would imagine it should be, since that's also possible in other blockchains - eg. Ethereum.

Please do note that I am interested in a solution that can be applied in a nodejs app, so a CLI method (if such exists) is not enough.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any signature in place of that parameter. For example, you can use `edsigtXomBKi5CTRf5cjATJWSyaRvhfYNHqSUGrn4SdbYRcGwQrUGjzEfQDTuqHhuA8b2d8NarZjz8TRf65WkpQmo423BtomS8Q` and it should return the RPC call.